# Duda sobre consulta aplicación Fichar

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una pequeña consulta para ver si me orientáis ya que lo mismo me estoy complicando yo mismo... el caso es que estoy realizando una aplicación para que los trabajadores de mi empresa fichen, y lo guardo en la tabla fichar, y luego tengo otras dos tablas que me indican los cuadrantes de los trabajadores, tanto de la oficina como del taller "para saber que días tienen que fichar" la cuestión es que quiero en un apartado que tengo de alertas que me genere un listado con todos los trabajadores que deberían haber fichado ese día y no lo han hecho, tenia pensado hacerlo así pero creo que me estoy liando yo mismo.

Esta es la consulta que me devuelve todos los trabajadores de la oficina que tienen que fichar un día en concreto:

```
SELECT *,t.Nombre as tNombre,t.Tipo as Tipo,rt.Tipo as estado,e.Nombre as Empresa 
FROM registrooficina rt 
INNER JOIN trabajadores t ON rt.CodTrabajador=t.Codigotrab 
    AND NOT t.Tipo='Conductor' 
INNER JOIN empresa e ON t.Codigoempre=e.Codigoemp 
WHERE Anio=2019 
    AND Dia=12 
    AND Mes=06 
    AND rt.Tipo='Trabajo'
```

Este es el resultado de los que tienen que fichar hoy de la oficina
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es la consulta que me devuelve todos los demas trabajadores que tienen que fichar un dia concreto:

```
SELECT *,t.Nombre as tNombre FROM registrotrabajadores rt 
INNER JOIN trabajadores t ON rt.CodTrabajador=t.Codigotrab 
INNER JOIN lineas l ON rt.Linea=l.Linea 
WHERE Anio=2019 
    AND Dia=12 
    AND Mes=06 
ORDER BY l.Codlinea ASC
```

Estos son los de que tienen que fichar hoy de los trabajadores
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y esta es la consulta que me devuelve todos los trabajadores de taller y oficina que han fichado desde hoy a dos días atras

```
(SELECT CodTrabajador 
FROM fichar rt 
INNER JOIN trabajadores t ON rt.CodTrabajador=t.Codigotrab 
    AND NOT t.Tipo='Conductor' 
INNER JOIN empresa e ON t.Codigoempre=e.Codigoemp 
WHERE Firma IS NOT NULL 
    AND Fecha BETWEEN date_sub(curdate(), interval 2 day) and curdate() 
    AND Activo='Si' 
    AND Codigotrab>12 
ORDER BY Fecha ASC) 

UNION 

(SELECT CodTrabajador 
FROM fichar rt 
INNER JOIN trabajadores t ON rt.CodTrabajador=t.Codigotrab 
WHERE Firma IS NOT NULL 
    AND Tipo='CONDUCTOR' 
    AND Fecha BETWEEN date_sub(curdate(), interval 2 day) and curdate() 
    AND Activo='Si' 
    AND Codigotrab>12 
ORDER BY Fecha ASC)
```

Y estos son los trabajadores de oficina y taller que han firmado en los ultimos 2 dias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenia pensado unir los trabajadores de oficina y taller que tienen que fichar y hacer un "NOT IN" en la consulta que devuelve todos los que tienen que trabajar y por lo tanto fichar, pero claro hay me van a salir un listado de todos los que han fichado dos días atrás y no comprueba día por día, y el objetivo es que me compruebe que hayan fichado todos los días y si no que me lo saque en un listado con los que no han fichado o ese día o 2 días atrás.

> Lo que necesito es calcular todos los de oficina y taller tienen que
>   fichar, "unir con union las dos primeras consultas" y comprobar que no
>   se encuentren en la segunda consulta, así tengo un listado de todos
>   los trabajadores que no han fichado y debían hacerlo, pero el problema
>   es que quiero que liste los que no han fichado en los últimos dos
>   días, no solamente en un día concreto

Espero haberme explicado medio en condiciones un saludo y espero puedan ayudarme

Tabla registro trabajadores:

```
CREATE TABLE `registrotrabajadores` (
  `CodRegistrotrab` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CodTrabajador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Semana` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Dia` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Mes` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Anio` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `Linea` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `Turno` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `Horas` float NOT NULL,
  `Incidencia` float NOT NULL,
  `Mercadillo` float NOT NULL,
  `RefuerzoFeria` float NOT NULL,
  `Refuerzo` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `registrotrabajadores`
--

INSERT INTO `registrotrabajadores` (`CodRegistrotrab`, `CodTrabajador`, `Semana`, `Dia`, `Mes`, `Anio`, `Linea`, `Turno`, `Horas`, `Incidencia`, `Mercadillo`, `RefuerzoFeria`, `Refuerzo`) VALUES
(135899, 27, 24, 10, 6, 2019, '4', 'T', 8, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135900, 93, 24, 11, 6, 2019, '4', 'T', 8.45, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135901, 27, 24, 12, 6, 2019, '4', 'T', 8, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135902, 27, 24, 13, 6, 2019, '4', 'T', 8, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135903, 27, 24, 14, 6, 2019, '4', 'T', 8, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135904, 27, 24, 15, 6, 2019, '4', 'T', 7.45, 0, 0, 0, 4.4),
(135905, 357, 24, 16, 6, 2019, '4', 'T', 8.45, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135906, 29, 24, 10, 6, 2019, '8', 'M', 7.05, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135907, 29, 24, 11, 6, 2019, 'D', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135908, 29, 24, 12, 6, 2019, '8', 'M', 7.05, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135909, 29, 24, 13, 6, 2019, '8', 'M', 7.05, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135910, 29, 24, 14, 6, 2019, '8', 'M', 7.05, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135911, 122, 24, 15, 6, 2019, '8', 'M', 7.05, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135913, 34, 24, 10, 6, 2019, '14', 'M', 7.2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135914, 34, 24, 11, 6, 2019, 'D', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135915, 34, 24, 12, 6, 2019, '14', 'M', 7.2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135916, 34, 24, 13, 6, 2019, '14', 'M', 7.2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135917, 34, 24, 14, 6, 2019, '14', 'M', 7.2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135918, 34, 24, 15, 6, 2019, '14', 'M', 7.35, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135919, 34, 24, 16, 6, 2019, 'D', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135920, 39, 24, 10, 6, 2019, '19', 'M', 7.05, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135921, 378, 24, 11, 6, 2019, '19', 'M', 6, 0, 0, 0, -3.45),
(135922, 39, 24, 12, 6, 2019, '19', 'M', 7.05, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135923, 39, 24, 13, 6, 2019, '19', 'M', 7.05, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(135924, 39, 24, 14, 6, 2019, '19', 'M', 7.05, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Tabla registrotrabajadoresoficina:

```
CREATE TABLE `registrooficina` (
  `CodRegistro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CodTrabajador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Anio` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `Mes` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Semana` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Dia` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `DiaSemana` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Tipo` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `registrooficina` (`CodRegistro`, `CodTrabajador`, `Anio`, `Mes`, `Semana`, `Dia`, `DiaSemana`, `Tipo`) VALUES
(17353, 54, 2019, 6, 24, 10, 'Lunes', 'Trabajo'),
(17354, 54, 2019, 6, 24, 12, 'Miercoles', 'Trabajo'),
(17355, 54, 2019, 6, 24, 13, 'Jueves', 'Trabajo'),
(17356, 54, 2019, 6, 24, 14, 'Viernes', 'Trabajo'),
(17357, 54, 2019, 6, 24, 15, 'Sabado', 'Trabajo'),
(17358, 5003, 2019, 6, 24, 10, 'Lunes', 'Trabajo'),
(17359, 5003, 2019, 6, 24, 11, 'Martes', 'Trabajo'),
(17360, 5003, 2019, 6, 24, 12, 'Miercoles', 'Trabajo'),
(17361, 5003, 2019, 6, 24, 13, 'Jueves', 'Trabajo'),
(17362, 5003, 2019, 6, 24, 14, 'Viernes', 'Trabajo'),
(17363, 5003, 2019, 6, 24, 15, 'Sabado', 'Descanso'),
(17364, 3052, 2019, 6, 24, 10, 'Lunes', 'Trabajo'),
(17365, 3052, 2019, 6, 24, 12, 'Miercoles', 'Trabajo'),
(17366, 3052, 2019, 6, 24, 13, 'Jueves', 'Trabajo'),
(17367, 3052, 2019, 6, 24, 14, 'Viernes', 'Trabajo'),
(17368, 3052, 2019, 6, 24, 15, 'Sabado', 'Trabajo'),
(17369, 54, 2019, 6, 24, 11, 'Martes', 'Festivo'),
(17370, 990, 2019, 6, 24, 10, 'Lunes', 'Trabajo'),
(17371, 990, 2019, 6, 24, 12, 'Miercoles', 'Trabajo'),
(17372, 990, 2019, 6, 24, 13, 'Jueves', 'Trabajo'),
(17373, 990, 2019, 6, 24, 14, 'Viernes', 'Trabajo'),
(17374, 990, 2019, 6, 24, 15, 'Sabado', 'Trabajo'),
(17375, 989, 2019, 6, 24, 10, 'Lunes', 'Trabajo'),
(17376, 989, 2019, 6, 24, 12, 'Miercoles', 'Trabajo'),
(17377, 989, 2019, 6, 24, 13, 'Jueves', 'Trabajo');
```

Tabla fichar que son los que ya han fichado

```
CREATE TABLE `fichar` (
  `CodFicha` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CodTrabajador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `HoraInicio` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `HoraFin` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `HoraInicioT` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `HoraFinT` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `Linea` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Turno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Total` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Firma` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `fichar` (`CodFicha`, `CodTrabajador`, `Fecha`, `HoraInicio`, `HoraFin`, `HoraInicioT`, `HoraFinT`, `Linea`, `Turno`, `Total`, `Firma`) VALUES
(1, 3999, '2019-06-10', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Oficina', 'Partido', 0, '../documentos/firmas/4cede67242cef0d19f14bc079d9d336f.png'),
(2, 3999, '2019-06-12', '10:56:14', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Administrador', 'Partido', 0, NULL),
(3, 352, '2019-06-12', '12:26:29', '12:26:32', NULL, NULL, '1', 'M', 0, '../documentos/firmas/99c27ab7dbbbcbfad76e7208b8687b3c.png');
```

He realizado la siguiente consulta que me permite saber los que deberían haber firmado un día determinado y no lo hicieron, ahora solo me queda sacar que saque los que tenían que firmar y no lo hicieron hasta 2 días atrás y sacar luego su nombre y el día que no firmo.

Comment: Tu consulta me gusta, será un placer ayudarte. Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask].

Comment: Muchas gracias, espero me pueda ayudar, me estoy liando mucho y se que es una cosa sencilla, y encima me explico mal...

Comment: No te preocupes por las explicaciones, cuando tengamos los datos, ya te iremos pidiendo los detalles que necesitemos para darle forma a la consulta... Para ayudarte, es importante que nos pases el dataset en SQL con algunos datos de ejemplo (phpMyAdmin,Exportar).

Comment: perfecto, voy a cambiar los datos ya que hay datos de trabajadores personales que no puedo enviar

Comment: Eso es, o anonimízalos con un MD5(). Con un UPDATE lo puedes hacer en bloque...

Comment: como añado los archivos exportados por las consultas aqui?

Comment: Copiando y pegando el código en la pregunta, seleccionándolo y pulsando Ctrl+K. Si tienes muchos datos, quédate sólo con unos pocos registros de cada tabla. Son simplemente para hacer pruebas

Comment: ya he subido las dos tablas registro trabajadores y oficina, para que las consultas funcionen, solo hay que quitar los inner join (que los uso para ampliar datos luego en el informe) que no son necesarios para la consulta en si

Comment: Qué mala suerte, ninguno de los trabajadores que han fichado figuran en las tablas registrooficina o registrotrabajadores. Por cierto, ¿en qué se diferencian estas últimas tablas? ¿Puedes poner datos que sirvan para hacer un ejemplo y poner el resultado que esperas obtener para esos datos?

Comment: Si, fue un ejemplo de datos, en ese caso deberían de salir todos ya que no ha fichado ninguno de ellos, pero bueno muchas gracias por todo ya lo solucione con la manera que expuse abajo, aunque no es con la consulta con un poco de php y un bucle ya conseguí hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final no he conseguido hacerlo solo mediante la consulta y he tenido que recurrir a código php para obtener el resultado deseado, espero a alguien le sirva,  así ha quedado :

```
 //ALERTAS DE FALTAS DE FICHAR
$i=1;
$fecha=date("Y-m-d");
$anio=date("Y",strtotime($fecha));
$mes=date("m",strtotime($fecha));
$dia=date("d",strtotime($fecha));

while ($i<=3){

    $query5="SELECT t1.CodTrabajador,Nombre,CONCAT($anio,'-',$mes,'-',$dia) AS Fecha FROM 
            (SELECT rt.CodTrabajador,t.Nombre FROM registrooficina rt INNER JOIN trabajadores t ON rt.CodTrabajador=t.Codigotrab AND NOT t.Tipo='Conductor' INNER JOIN empresa e 
             ON t.Codigoempre=e.Codigoemp WHERE Anio=$anio AND Dia=$dia AND Mes=$mes AND rt.Tipo='Trabajo'
                UNION 
             SELECT rt.CodTrabajador,t.Nombre FROM registrotrabajadores rt INNER JOIN trabajadores t ON rt.CodTrabajador=t.Codigotrab INNER JOIN lineas l ON rt.Linea=l.Linea WHERE Anio=2019 AND Dia=12 AND Mes=06) as t1
                WHERE t1.CodTrabajador NOT IN 
            (SELECT CodTrabajador FROM fichar rt INNER JOIN trabajadores t ON rt.CodTrabajador=t.Codigotrab AND NOT t.Tipo='Conductor' INNER JOIN empresa e ON t.Codigoempre=e.Codigoemp WHERE Firma IS NOT NULL AND Fecha='$fecha' AND Activo='Si' AND Codigotrab>12                            
                UNION                                
            SELECT CodTrabajador FROM fichar rt INNER JOIN trabajadores t ON rt.CodTrabajador=t.Codigotrab WHERE Firma IS NOT NULL AND Tipo='CONDUCTOR' AND Fecha='$fecha' AND Activo='Si' AND Codigotrab>12)";

    $result5 = mysqli_query($conection, $query5);
    while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5)){
        $fecha=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row5['Fecha']));
        $fichajes[]=array(
            "CodTrabajador"=>$row5['CodTrabajador'],
            "Fecha"=>$fecha,
            "Nombre"=>$row5['Nombre'],
        );
    }
    $fecha = strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($fecha));
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d', $fecha);
    $anio=date("Y",strtotime($fecha));
    $mes=date("m",strtotime($fecha));
    $dia=date("d",strtotime($fecha));
    $i++;
}
```